# WordPress plugin, track ajax progress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, session-variables, progress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin. At the admin page, I have a ajax call that does a lengthy process behind. The ajax call was done using jQuery.

I can't find much option to implement progress tracking from ajax side. So I decided to store the progress in the user's session variable in php, then have another ajax call to check on that session variable in fixed interval.

But this leads to another problem, I don't find any indication to store user session variable in wordpress. I'm looking at using wp_cache. I'm trying not to touch the db, or extensive modification to wordpress itself.

I need this as universal as possible. What are the options available?

EDIT: I just realized that $GLOBALS doesn't persist over to the next http call. I did some test and found that the flag I store in $GLOBALS always reset itself at every call. Hmm...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What's wrong with `$_SESSION`?

Comment: WordPress unset $_SESSION on every call. Using it the plugin might seems a bit out of place (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_YQcV6tj8GcJ:www.thinkingoutloud.co.za/content/20091012/php_wordpress_and_session+wordpress+$_session&hl=en&gl=my&strip=1), unless there's no alternative. I'm trying out user_meta, seems ok for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I've settle with using user_meta to store the variable. As the lengthy process is associated per user. That should handle it.